# MS Teams webhook with markdown

Tags: markdown, microsoft-teams

I have a channel in  MS Teams, and webhook, connected to this channel. I use webhook to send messages to the channel. I don't use API. And I don't understand, behavior of markdown.
To send message I use postman and webhook URL.
Also I use [Available Markdown actions in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772) instruction.
When I send:
`{ "title": "Hellooo!!!", "text": "~Message~", "themeColor": "" }`, I get "~Message~" instead of the crossed out word `{ "title": "Hellooo!!!", "text": "*Message*", "themeColor": "" }` I get italic word instead bold.

Could you answer, do I have to use some special syntax, or sending simple messages through webhook doesn't work correct.

Thanks at advise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your
question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four
spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Please also include some details about how you are sending this. What API endpoint are you hitting, for example? Are you including any other parameters?

Comment: Sorry for unclear description, I've corrected it.

Comment: MS teams markdown support is woeful: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/37096132--actual-markdown-support   https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772

Answer (score 0):

`*Italic*` will display italic text, if you want to display text as bold use `**Bold**`.
For more information please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#text-formatting).

Comment: Thank you. But examples from documentation also don't work correct. When I send: { "title": "Hellooo!!!", "text": "~~Message~~", "themeColor": "" }, I get "~~Message~~" instead of the crossed out word. And `#### header` looks bigger than `# header`.

Comment: @Максим Гончар, I have raised a bug and concerned team is working on it.

Comment: 1)For strike through, markdown doesn't seem to be working, will need to check with Connectors team. the work around is to use HTML tag instead for this.<strike>Message</strike>
2)Headers need to be at start of the line or a carriage return need to be specified.
`learn \r#  more \r## about \r### actionable Messages`.